# Firemonkey component style don't work if created at runtime

Tags: delphi, runtime, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

My problem.
I an creating `TListBoxItem` and a `TLabel` in runtime.
All components are created but `TLabel` style is not applied.

Do I have to call any other functions to apply style?

My code:

```
// LIST ITEM
LB_Item := TListBoxItem.Create(POSTAVKE);
with LB_Item do
begin
  Parent := POSTAVKE;
  Height := 50;
  Selectable := True;
end;
// LABEL 1
LB_Label1 := TLabel.Create(nil);
with LB_Label1 do
begin
  Parent := LB_Item;
  Align := TAlignLayout.alLeft;
  Width := 50;
  Font.Size := 12;
  TextAlign := TTextAlign.taCenter;
  Text := IntToStr(Kolicina);
  Font.Size := 14;
  Font.Style := [TFontStyle.fsBold];
  FontColor := TAlphaColorRec.Darkslategray;
  HitTest := False;
end;

......

Application.ProcessMessages;
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At runtime you need to change the value in the StyledSettings property:

```
StyledSettings := StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.ssFamily, TStyledSetting.ssSize, TStyledSetting.ssStyle];
```

should do it for you.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Types.TStyledSetting